# Failing to do Projection in JPA query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Sorry for the messy SQL query.

I have this data structure

```
@Entity
public class Stock {

//Composite PK?
@Id
@NotNull
private String id;
@NotNull
private String product_id;
@NotNull
private Integer quantity;
@NotNull
private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

And

```
public class ProductSold {

    private String productId;
    private Integer itemsSold;
```

Both classes with proper constructors.

I have the according repository for the Stock

```
public interface StockRepository extends JpaRepository<Stock, String> {
```

What I'm trying to do is a tricky SQL query (the comment is easier to visualise the query) where it should return me a List of ProductSold instead of Stock

```
 /*
SELECT (t1.quantity - t2.quantity) as itemsSold, t1.product_id as pd
FROM stock t1 CROSS JOIN
 stock t2
WHERE MONTH(t1.timestamp) = 8 AND DAY(t1.timestamp) = 26
AND MONTH(t2.timestamp) = 8 AND DAY(t2.timestamp) = 27
AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id
ORDER BY itemsSold DESC
LIMIT 3;
 */

//Not working, not too sure why, says it can't find column quantity. In my view it should be working since it's a valid SQL Query.
@Query(value = "SELECT  new com.stock.stock.model.ProductSold(t1.product_id as productId, (t1.quantity - t2.quantity) as itemsSold )" +
        "    FROM Stock t1 CROSS JOIN Stock t2" +
        "    WHERE MONTH(t1.timestamp) = ?1 AND DAY(t1.timestamp) = ?2" +
        "    AND MONTH(t2.timestamp) = ?3 AND DAY(t2.timestamp) = ?4" +
        "    AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id" +
        "    ORDER BY itemsSold DESC" +
        "    LIMIT 3", nativeQuery = true)
List<ProductSold> findItemsSoldByTimestamp(int month1, int day1, int month2, int day2);
```

But I'm getting this:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT  NEW COM.[*]STOCK.STOCK.MODEL.PRODUCTSOLD(T1.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCTID, (T1.QUANTITY - T2.QUANTITY) AS ITEMSSOLD ) ....

Any idea what is wrong? I've tried not construction in the SQL expression but I get a ConverterNotFoundException

Comment: i don't think it is a native query

Comment: But if I take the native query out, it doesn't allow me to create the object inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a constructor expression which is only available in JPQL, but you also mark you query as native, i.e. SQL which it isn't.

Comment: But if I take the native query out, it doesn't allow me to create the object inside the query.

Comment: The opposite is true, only when it is not a native query, you may use a constructor expression. Of course you'd then have to fix the rest of the query, for example remove the limit clause which isn't supported by JPQL.